# Select list out of a list?

Tags: prolog

I have a list of `persons` and `parent` facts

```
person(nameA).
person(nameB).
person(nameC).

parent(parentname, children).
```

I need to write a rule `hasnochild(X).` to iterates through all `person` that has no child.

This is what I have wrote thus far. 
`hasnochild(X) :- parent(Z, X).`
But it returns all the person's name who has a child. How do I get those who have no child?

Something like the whole list of `person` minus off what I have wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try to unify Person (`X` in your question) with a person in the database, then succeed only if that person does not have children.

E.g.:

```
hasnochild(X):-
  person(X),         % X is a Person
  \+ parent(X, _).  % with no children
```

The call to `person(X)` may be avoided if you know that the first argument to `parent/2` is a person.

Comment: May I know what does this `\+` mean?

Comment: Check the documentation for [\+](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%2B)/1). It will succeed if the goal inside does not succeed.

Comment: Alright. Anyway ur answer will give a list of person who has a child. I am looking for person who has no child. Should use `\+(parent(_, X).` instead.

Comment: @MaTaKazer: The code provided already calls `\+(parent(_, X))`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `\+(parent(X, _))`

Comment: @false: Right, removed them