# Node has no descendant

Tags: prolog

I have a rule

```
% X is descendant of Y
descendant(X,Y) :-
```

I am trying to write a rule that will find out which node has no descendant. How do I tell prolog that I want to find every X that fails `descendant(X,_)`.

I tried this it doesn't give the correct result.

```
nodescendants(X) :- \+(descendant(X, _)).
```

**Edited to update my question.** Actually what I am finding is more strict.

Given the following facts and rules.

```
cyborg(greatgrandparent).
cyborg(grandparent).

female(parent).

male(child).

cyborg(child2).

female(jr_child).

parent(greatgrandparent, grandparent).
parent(grandparent, parent).
parent(parent, child).
parent(parent, child2).
parent(child, jr_child).

% X is descendant of Y
descendant(X,Y) :-

% C is cyborg descendant of Y
cyborg_descendant(C,Y) :-

is_human_or_cyborg(X) :-
      human(X)
   ;  cyborg(X).

has_no_cyborg_descendants(X) :-
   is_human_or_cyborg(X),
   \+(cyborg_descendant(_, X)).
```

When I did a run to find all person(cyborg+ all humans) that do not have cyborg descendants, 'grandparent' got flagged as true, which should not be the case. As grandparent -> parent -> child2 which is a cyborg.

```
?- has_no_cyborg_descendants(X).
X = child ;
X = jr_child ;
X = grandparent ;
X = child2.
```

Comment: The solution to this is actually provided in the answer to your very similar question, [Select list out of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179848/select-list-out-of-a-list). In order to generate non-descendents, you need a way to identify whether `X` is a valid descendent (exists in the "universe of all possible descendents").

Comment: @lurker updated my question

Comment: `cyborg_desccendant(child2, grandparent)` fails because in your definition  either `grandparent` must be the parent of `child2` (which it isn't), or `child2` must have a parent which is cyborg descendant of `grandparent`, which it doesn't. So `grandparent`, according to your `cyborg_descendant` logic, has no cyborg descendants (`cyborg_descendant(_, grandparent)` fails).

Comment: By the way, you need to group your like facts together. So keep `cyborg/1` facts together and `female/1` facts together. Not all Prolog interpreters will see all of your facts if they aren't contiguous. You might see a warning such as, *warning: discontiguous predicate cyborg/1 - clause ignored* (from GNU Prolog).

Comment: @lurker alright. I will have to think this through to make it in such a way that it's false as long as any of the descendants along the chain down is a cyborg

Comment: Think about the logic of your `cyborg_descendent` predicate. I think it doesn't match what you intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that `grandparent` should have a cyborg descendant due to the descendancy: `grandparent` -> `parent` -> `child2`. However, the following query fails:

```
cyborg_descendant(child2, grandparent).
```

In fact, this query also fails:

```
cyborg_descendant(_, grandparent).
```

So clearly there's something wrong with the logic in `cyborg_descendant/2`. This is resulting in `has_no_cyborg_descendants(grandparent)` succeeding.

Additionally, you have an issue with splitting up your like facts. Prolog expects like facts (facts with the same functor name) to be grouped together, or some may be ignored. So the following:

```
cyborg(greatgrandparent).
cyborg(grandparent).

female(parent).

male(child).

cyborg(child2).

female(jr_child).
```

Can result in `female(jr_child)` and `cyborg(child2)` being ignored. The Prolog interpreter warns about this. You should rewrite this as:

```
cyborg(greatgrandparent).
cyborg(grandparent).
cyborg(child2).

female(parent).
female(jr_child).

male(child).
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote nondescendant/1 you are not describing anything to match only something not to match. If you want concrete answers specify what you are looking for. For example: if you had a predicate person/1 that describes all the known people and you want to know who of them is not a descendant, you could ask for a person that is not a descendant:

```
person(a).
person(b).
person(c).
person(d).

descendant(a,b).
descendant(b,c).
descendant(c,d).

nondescendant(X) :-
    person(X),
    \+(descendant(X,_)).


?- nondescendant(X).
X = d
```

Or stick with your definition of nondescendant/1 and use it in conjunction with another goal:

```
?- person(X), nondescendant(X).
X = d
```

Comment: updated my question. I have tried your method and it works well if there is only 1 type of person, but now I have 3 different kind of `person`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your `nodescendants/1` predicate works fine, when used for a specific node.

If you want to *find all* X, use [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3). But the interpreter has to know which nodes to consider, so you need to account for that as well. You can't expect the interpreter to figure out all nodes by itself.